# How to make liquid escape content inside math block

Tags: liquid, mathjax, kramdown

I am using Jekyll with Kramdown and MathJax. In my markdown, even though the math block is delimited by $$ double dollar, I am getting liquid parse error

```
.....
$$
a = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}\\a_{2}\\a_{3}\ 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_{1} & a_{2} &a_{3}\end{bmatrix}
 \vec a = \left\langle {{a_1},{a_2},{a_3}} \right\rangle ---> Line 35
$$
....
```

error

```
home/alex/gems/gems/liquid-4.0.0/lib/liquid/block_body.rb:132:in `raise_missing_variable_terminator': Liquid syntax error (line 35): Variable '{{a_1}' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\\}\\}/ (Liquid::SyntaxError)
```

The Jekyll _config.yaml

```
# Markdown specs
markdown: kramdown
mathjax: true

kramdown:
  auto_ids:       true
  footnote_nr:    1
  entity_output:  as_char
  footnote_backlink: "&#x21a9;&#xfe0e;"
  toc_levels:     1..6
  smart_quotes:   lsquo,rsquo,ldquo,rdquo
  enable_coderay: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Mathjax.js is not loaded from Github through HTTP. So we need to use HTTPS

Add this to your default.html in the _layouts folder if you are using Jekyll

```
<script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And if you are using single dollar $ for inline maths, you can add the following to the head.html in layouts

```
  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
      tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
        processEscapes: true
      }
    });
```

https://github.com/alexcpn/alexcpn.github.io/tree/master/_layouts